# Move data from on input field to another and submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get one input field that is higher up the page, move it's content to a form field at the bottom of the page and submit the form.

Please see what I have done here (doesn't work):

```js
$('#move_down').click(function() {
    $('#input_1').val($('#input_2').val())
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input_1" value="">
<br>
<button id="move_down">Click Here</button>
<br>
<input type="text" id="input_2" value="">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.js"></script>
```

Moving the data is just the first part, I am also trying to get it to take the user down to the main form and submit it - is this possible with jQuery?

Updated the question to fix my silly error of omitting the ID selectors. Just need to figure out how to submit the form now.

Comment: Where are your ID `#` selectors? Where is your `<form>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right; just correct your query selector:

```
$('#move_down').click(function() {
    $('#input_2').val($('#input_1').val())
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/82x28ryr/4/

Comment: Ah yeah, silly mistake! Any idea how I would then make the form submit after?

Comment: give your form to id="myform" then 
$('#myform').submit();

Comment: That works fine for a normal form, but when I try submitting an Ajax form it just refreshes the page - any way around that?

Comment: then you should catch form submit event  and prevent default and use jquery xhr on this event

Comment: i tell him before but they point charliefti's answer wow :D he stole my answer :D

Comment: Thanks for the help! Instead of using the .submit I used the 'click' function on the button - works a charm.

Comment: well then congrats !

Answer (score 1):

Missing the `#` prefix for id selector

Works fine doing

```js
$('#move_down').click(function() {
    $('#input_2').val($('#input_1').val())
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input_1" value="">
<br>
<button id="move_down">Click Here</button>
<br>
<input type="text" id="input_2" value="">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.js"></script>
```

As for "moving down" you have only provided html in demo for 2 inputs. You need to update question with all relevant html in order to implement additional features

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan probably right. i just went with existing structure